# var_dump on interactive mode shows unexpected result

Tags: php

I'm on my shell (ubuntu 12) and encountered a strange behaviour, which I can't explain:

> var_dump(array(1.5 => "a", 2.2 => "b", 2.5 => "c"));

prints the following in my shell:

```
array(2) {
    [1]=>
    string(1) "a"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "c"
}
```

can someone please explain this? What happens to "b"? Why is it not printed? 
(PHP 5.3)

Comment: The manual can: [*Floats are also cast to integers, which means that the fractional part will be truncated. E.g. the key 8.7 will actually be stored under 8*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: `2.2` is taken as 2. And, `2.5` is also taken as 2. In this case, `2.5` overrides `2.2` as both value are 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two things going on here:

1. Array keys can only be strings or integers. Floats will be cast to integers.
2. If multiple elements in the array declaration use the same key, only the last one will be used as all others are overwritten.

So your `2.2` and `2.5` keys were cast to the integer `2`. The second one overwrote the first one.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-99

---

One option would be to use string keys:

```
var_dump(array("1.5" => "a", "2.2" => "b", "2.5" => "c"));

array(3) {
  '1.5' =>
  string(1) "a"
  '2.2' =>
  string(1) "b"
  '2.5' =>
  string(1) "c"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Type Casting and Overwriting example**

```
<?php
$array = array(
    1    => "a",
    2.2  => "b",
    2.5  => "c",
);
var_dump($array);
?>
```

The above example will **output**:

```
array(2) {
    [1]=>
    string(1) "a"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "c"
}
```

As in the above example `2.2` & `2.5` are cast to `2`, the value will be `overwritten` on every new element and the last assigned value "c" is the only one left over.

For more info, please click [Type Casting and Overwriting example](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-100)